# Linking 2 json file on my map

Tags: json, google-maps

I want to use 2 or more json file to produce markers (easier to make changes as files are shorter).
The files are identical in construction, but when I add them to my code I only get the details from the last one.

I renamed the data to var jsonsl and var jsonpm, but can't seem to get it to merge both.

Code I can get to work is this, but only works on one file at a time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapping_1sl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapping_1pm.js"></script>

var gmarkers = [];
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.995391,-3.795069);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);



var categoryIcons = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonsl.length; i++) {
          var data = jsonsl[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map : map,
            title : data.Name,
            icon : categoryIcons[data.ConnectorType],
      });
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

More info:

Files are set up the same, just different names:

```
var jsonsl = [{
        "Name" : "2 Riddons Road",
        "Latitude" : 51.43145362,
        "Longitude" : 0.031174836,
        "PostCode" : "SE12 9QR",
        "Address" : "Riddons Road, jctn with Chinbrook Road, Lewisham , London, SE12 9QR",
        "Count" : 1,
        "Information" : "3-pin square",
        "Connection" : "BS 1363",
        "ChargeRate" : "Standard (up to 3.7kW, 13-16A)",
        "ConnectorType" : 1,
        "Operator" : "Source London",

    }]
```

and

```
var jsonpm = [{
        "Name" : "Cornthwaite Road",
        "Latitude" : 51.55798957,
        "Longitude" : -0.052563915,
        "PostCode" : "E5 9QL",
        "Address" : "Cornthwaite Road south of Thistlethwaite Road, Hackney, London, E5 9QL",
        "Count" : 1,
        "Information" : "7-pin 'Smart' eg Mennekes",
        "Connection" : "IEC 62196 Fast",
        "ChargeRate" : "Fast (7kW, 32A)",
        "ConnectorType" : 2,
        "Operator" : "Source London",       
    }]
```

Comment: What do those files look like?  Do they use (overwrite) the same variable?

Comment: Files are set up the same just named differently.

Comment: Then that is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only process in the data in one of the files (jsons1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonsl.length; i++) {
      var data = jsonsl[i],
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map : map,
        title : data.Name,
        icon : categoryIcons[data.ConnectorType],
  });
}
```

You need to process both:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonsl.length; i++) {
      var data = jsonsl[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map : map,
        title : data.Name,
        icon : categoryIcons[data.ConnectorType],
      });
}
for (var i = 0; i < jsonspm.length; i++) {
      var data = jsonspm[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map : map,
        title : data.Name,
        icon : categoryIcons[data.ConnectorType],
      });
}
```

(if you are going to be doing this more you could make it a function that takes the name of the data and adds it to the map)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, have tried and works well, will tinker to try and compress a little.